# Translation program in JAVA

Tags: java, translation, do-while

So, Me and my friend made an English to Al Bhed (a dialect from FFX) code in JAVA. I'd like to implement the "characters inside the brackets (or []) aren't translated" thing but I can't figure out how to. Can somebody help me implement it? Here's the code. It's not in full array format because I'm not really familiar with arrays.

```
import java.io.*;

class albhed
    {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

            int a;
            String b;

            System.out.println("English to Al Bhed, input 1.");
            System.out.println("Al Bhed to English, input 2.");
            b = dataIn.readLine();
            a = Integer.parseInt(b);
            if (a == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter English characters to translate.");
                    String x = dataIn.readLine();
                    int y = x.length();
                    String z[] = x.split("");
                    System.out.println("The translated characters from English to Al Bhed:");
                    for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)
                        {
                            switch (z[i])
                                {
                                    case "A": System.out.print("Y"); break;
                                    case "B": System.out.print("P"); break;
                                    case "C": System.out.print("L"); break;
                                    case "D": System.out.print("T"); break;
                                    case "E": System.out.print("A"); break;
                                    case "F": System.out.print("V"); break;
                                    case "G": System.out.print("K"); break;
                                    case "H": System.out.print("R"); break;
                                    case "I": System.out.print("E"); break;
                                    case "J": System.out.print("Z"); break;
                                    case "K": System.out.print("G"); break;
                                    case "L": System.out.print("M"); break;
                                    case "M": System.out.print("S"); break;
                                    case "N": System.out.print("H"); break;
                                    case "O": System.out.print("U"); break;
                                    case "P": System.out.print("B"); break;
                                    case "Q": System.out.print("X"); break;
                                    case "R": System.out.print("N"); break;
                                    case "S": System.out.print("C"); break;
                                    case "T": System.out.print("D"); break;
                                    case "U": System.out.print("I"); break;
                                    case "V": System.out.print("J"); break;
                                    case "W": System.out.print("F"); break;
                                    case "X": System.out.print("Q"); break;
                                    case "Y": System.out.print("O"); break;
                                    case "Z": System.out.print("W"); break;
                                    case "a": System.out.print("y"); break;
                                    case "b": System.out.print("p"); break;
                                    case "c": System.out.print("l"); break;
                                    case "d": System.out.print("t"); break;
                                    case "e": System.out.print("a"); break;
                                    case "f": System.out.print("v"); break;
                                    case "g": System.out.print("k"); break;
                                    case "h": System.out.print("r"); break;
                                    case "i": System.out.print("e"); break;
                                    case "j": System.out.print("z"); break;
                                    case "k": System.out.print("g"); break;
                                    case "l": System.out.print("m"); break;
                                    case "m": System.out.print("s"); break;
                                    case "n": System.out.print("h"); break;
                                    case "o": System.out.print("u"); break;
                                    case "p": System.out.print("b"); break;
                                    case "q": System.out.print("x"); break;
                                    case "r": System.out.print("n"); break;
                                    case "s": System.out.print("c"); break;
                                    case "t": System.out.print("d"); break;
                                    case "u": System.out.print("i"); break;
                                    case "v": System.out.print("j"); break;
                                    case "w": System.out.print("f"); break;
                                    case "x": System.out.print("q"); break;
                                    case "y": System.out.print("o"); break;
                                    case "z": System.out.print("w"); break;
                                    default: System.out.print(z[i]); break;
                                }
                        }
                }
            else if (a == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter Al Bhed characters to translate.");
                    String x = dataIn.readLine();
                    int y = x.length();
                    String z[] = x.split("");
                    System.out.println("The translated characters from Al Bhed to English:");
                    for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)
                        {
                            switch (z[i])
                                {
                                    case "Y": System.out.print("A"); break;
                                    case "P": System.out.print("B"); break;
                                    case "L": System.out.print("C"); break;
                                    case "T": System.out.print("D"); break;
                                    case "A": System.out.print("E"); break;
                                    case "V": System.out.print("F"); break;
                                    case "K": System.out.print("G"); break;
                                    case "R": System.out.print("H"); break;
                                    case "E": System.out.print("I"); break;
                                    case "Z": System.out.print("J"); break;
                                    case "G": System.out.print("K"); break;
                                    case "M": System.out.print("L"); break;
                                    case "S": System.out.print("M"); break;
                                    case "H": System.out.print("N"); break;
                                    case "U": System.out.print("O"); break;
                                    case "B": System.out.print("P"); break;
                                    case "X": System.out.print("Q"); break;
                                    case "N": System.out.print("R"); break;
                                    case "C": System.out.print("S"); break;
                                    case "D": System.out.print("T"); break;
                                    case "I": System.out.print("U"); break;
                                    case "J": System.out.print("V"); break;
                                    case "F": System.out.print("W"); break;
                                    case "Q": System.out.print("X"); break;
                                    case "O": System.out.print("Y"); break;
                                    case "W": System.out.print("Z"); break;
                                    case "y": System.out.print("a"); break;
                                    case "p": System.out.print("b"); break;
                                    case "l": System.out.print("c"); break;
                                    case "t": System.out.print("d"); break;
                                    case "a": System.out.print("e"); break;
                                    case "v": System.out.print("f"); break;
                                    case "k": System.out.print("g"); break;
                                    case "r": System.out.print("h"); break;
                                    case "e": System.out.print("i"); break;
                                    case "z": System.out.print("j"); break;
                                    case "g": System.out.print("k"); break;
                                    case "m": System.out.print("l"); break;
                                    case "s": System.out.print("m"); break;
                                    case "h": System.out.print("n"); break;
                                    case "u": System.out.print("o"); break;
                                    case "b": System.out.print("p"); break;
                                    case "x": System.out.print("q"); break;
                                    case "n": System.out.print("r"); break;
                                    case "c": System.out.print("s"); break;
                                    case "d": System.out.print("t"); break;
                                    case "i": System.out.print("u"); break;
                                    case "j": System.out.print("v"); break;
                                    case "f": System.out.print("w"); break;
                                    case "q": System.out.print("x"); break;
                                    case "o": System.out.print("y"); break;
                                    case "w": System.out.print("z"); break;
                                    default: System.out.print(z[i]); break;
                                }
                        }
                }
            else
                {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("\nINPUT 1 OR 2 ONLY.");
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what problem you are having?

Comment: I could not understand your problem when i try with your programme I Can see the characters in side the brackets are also translating

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I'd like the characters to not be translated when they're inside the brackets.

Comment: Those 2 huge switch-case blocks seems redundant and like code duplication to me. You could just use a `Map`, that would make the coder better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use a boolean to store the fact that you don't want to translate any character each time you encounter a `[`, until you find any `]`

```
                boolean must_translate = true;
                for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)
                    {
                        if (z[i].equals("[")) { must_translate = false; }
                        else if (z[i].equals("]")) { must_translate = true; }
                        else {
                           if (must_translate) {
                               switch (z[i])
                               // (....)
                           } else {
                               System.out.print(z[i]);
                           }
                        }
```

Of course, you code is far from being optimal, but that's not the point.

(Just for information : you don't have to split you string to smaller string. It's better to directly access to the char's at soem index of the string. Also, it would be better to build a StringBuffer object, and print it at the end, instead of calling System.out.print for each character. And your switch part is very long. It would be better to store the translation rules in an array or a map.)

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the problem. I'll do my best to use your suggestion.

Comment: But what if I'd like the non-translated part to have brackets too? Example, [you] yna ysywehk?

Comment: then remove the `else {` line before `if (must_translate)`. And start learning some basic programming skills ;) (no offense)